# Should "the" be used here?

Tags: grammar, articles

Extracting data from the web can serve a broad spectrum of data-centric applications. 
The human effort required in large scale extraction tasks signicantly affects both the flexibility and the cost.

Should "the" at the beginning of the second sentence be used?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"The" is required before "human effort" because that noun phrase is modified by the restrictive reduced clause "required in large-scale extraction tasks."

Notice how "the" is no longer necessary in this more general statement:

- Human effort is always required for large-scale extraction tasks.

Also notice that the definite article should be eliminated in the last phrase:

- ... both flexibility and cost.